# States and Behaviors for the WPF developer, where to find informational resources?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, expression-blend

I've been doing WPF programming the "old fashioned" way (See charles petzold's applications = code + markup for the age of my extensions), and was recently becoming used to Blend 3, only thing is, there is this whole world I'm missing out on, sketchflow, states, transitions, behaviors, the VSM, all this I seem to be totally missing out on.  Where can I find some good resources on the subject.  I prefer in-depth books over web articles, but I'll take either at this point.

Answer (score 1):

For all new stuff in WPF world I would highly recommend you to use [WPF Disciplies blog](http://wpfdisciples.wordpress.com/). [Rudi Grobler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5147/rudigrobler) has a [list of WPF stars](http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2009/01/21/wpf-disciples.aspx) who drives WPF universe beyond our imagination. BTW you can find some of them here :). You can also [get OPML file here](http://dotnet.org.za/files/folders/938863/download.aspx), to import to your favourite RSS reader.

Back to your question. Marlon Grech has [the answer](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/blend-3-and-sketchflow/) :)

Answer (score 0):

For states and behaviors, there is some info on my blog at www.electricbeach.org. I just recently posted an article with lots of information on writing behaviors with many links included.

See http://electricbeach.org/?p=353